# i can't run my flutter project on the android emulator

Tags: flutter, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\app development\test2\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.72/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.72.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:4.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:4.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:4.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder-model:4.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:common:27.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:27.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:27.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:27.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:27.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:27.1.0 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:27.1.0
> Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm:7.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm/7.0/asm-7.0.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0
> Could not find org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:7.0.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/7.0/asm-analysis-7.0.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' \     Required by:
> unspecified:unspecified:unspecified > com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0 > com.android.tools.build:builder:4.1.0 > com.android.tools:sdklib:27.1.0 > com.android.tools:repository:27.1.0

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: check your internet connection and run the project again

Answer (score 0):

Open Flutter Terminal run...

**flutter clean**

**flutter pub get**

**##then**

**update your classpath**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that but another problem I have is why can android version 5 run on my emulator and others can't they just stuck on a black screen and other on the Google loading

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, open another question with this instead of answering your own question with another question.

Answer (score 0):

in gradle.wrapper.properties update distributionUrl to the latest
version